# Powershell 4 Get-ScheduledTask and Windows

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

I thought no matter what OS you had, if you had Powershell installed, you would have access to the same default cmdlets.

So I want to use [Get-ScheduledTask](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649808.aspx) on my Windows 7 machine.  I have Powershell 4 installed.  However, when I run it, I get the error:

```
Get-ScheduledTask : The term 'Get-ScheduledTask' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ScheduledTask
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ScheduledTask:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I run on my Windows 8.1 with Powershell 4 already pre-installed along with the OS, it works.

Can I get the cmdlets on my Windows 7 machine?  There is nothing on the Microsoft Get-ScheduledTask page about Windows 7 so I am guessing not.

If not then would it be a case of using the command line:

[scheduled task command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641619/windows-7-scheduled-task-command-line)

No doubt someone will point me at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151631/powershellpack-taskscheduler-module-run-task-with-no-logged-user) but that was for Powershell 2.  I am on Powershell 4.

Now I am a big fan of not reinventing the wheel, but this [guys scripts](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/11/22/managing-scheduled-tasks-in-your-environment-part-ii/) look a good alternative.

Answer (score 6):

`Get-ScheduledTask` relies on underlying features of the OS that Windows 7 doesn't have, so there is no way to run the cmdlet on that OS, even with PowerShell v4. In your case, you can either leverage `schtasks.exe` or the `Schedule.Service` COM object.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151631/powershellpack-taskscheduler-module-run-task-with-no-logged-user) that you linked gives the best overview of these methods, but in the interests of completeness, I'll link the relevant resources here:

[schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

[MS PowerShellPack TaskScheduler module](https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover-PowerShell/tree/master/modules/TaskScheduler) -> (leverages the `Schedule.Service` COM object)